# jquery using c# webclient .net namespace?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have the following JQUERY code that relates to a html document from a website.

```
$
```

Anything is appreciated,

Salute.

Comment: You will need a lib to parse the html string like HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: jQuery and c# are not interchangeable, so there isn't a direct translation from the javascript you write for your jQuery, to c#. Do you mean that you are trying to generate the javascript in your example by using c#?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can remember using the HtmlAgilityPack

```
var rawText = "<html><head><head><body><div id='container'><article><p>stuff<p></article><article><p>stuff2</p></article></div></body></html>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(rawText);

var stuff = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .SelectMany(div => div.Descendants("article"));
var length = stuff.Count();
var textValues = stuff.Select(a => a.InnerHtml).ToList();
```

Output:
`length: 2`

`textValues: List<String> (2 items)
<p>stuff<p>
<p>stuff2</p>`

To get the HTML, instead of hardcoding it as above, use the `WebClient` class since it has a simplier API than `WebRequest`.

```
var client = new WebClient();
var html = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/file.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically related to using the System.Net namespace you would do this:

1. go here to see the way to use the WebRequest class itself to get the
   content.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
2. Next after you get the content back you need to parse it using HTMLAgility pack found here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

How would one code the JQUERY into C#, this is an untested example:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();  
doc.Load(@"D:\test.html");  //you can also use a memory stream instead.
var  container = doc.GetElementbyId("continer");
foreach (HtmlNode node in container.Elements("img"))
{
    HtmlAttribute valueAttribute = node.Attributes["value"];
    if (valueAttribute != null) Console.WriteLine(valueAttribute.Value);

}
```

In your case the attributes you want after you find the element are  alt, src, and href

It will take you about 1 day to learn agilitypack but it's mature fast and well liked by the community.